# Override the property of an abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, overriding, abstract

I want to output the `numberOfLegs` of my tiger1 instance. But the output is 0 instead of my expected 4. Where is my mistake? Please help the tiger to get his legs back.

```
using System;

namespace AbstractProperty
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tiger tiger1 = new Tiger();
            int result = tiger1.NumberOfLegs;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.Read();
        }

        public abstract class Animal
        {
            public abstract int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
        }

        public class Tiger : Animal
        {
            private int numberOfLegs;
            public override int NumberOfLegs
            {
                get
                {
                    return numberOfLegs;
                }
                set
                {
                    numberOfLegs = 4;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I think it is not good to use `numberOfLegs = 4` in a Setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, the `set` accessor for `NumberOfLegs` is never called, thus `numberOfLegs` has the default value 0.
You could write a constructor and assign some value to `NumberOfLegs`, which would be assigned 4 anyway as you have hard-coded 4 in the `set` accessor, i.e. if you write your constructor like this:

```
public Tiger() {
  NumberOfLegs = 10;
}
```

The `set` accessor would be called and assign `4` (not `10`) to `numberOfLegs`. Perhaps you have mixed up the concepts a bit here :)

**EDIT 1:** If you now understand that assigning a hard-coded value in the setter was not that great, and you don't want to do anything special in the setter, it would be better to use the traditional approach for properties:

```
private int numberOfLegs;
public override int NumberOfLegs
{
    get
    {
        return numberOfLegs;
    }
    set
    {
        numberOfLegs = value;
    }
}
```

Or simply

```
public override int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
```

which does the same thing as above.
And assign value to `NumberOfLegs` in the constructor:

```
public Tiger() 
{
  NumberOfLegs = 4;
}
```

Comment: This was my first try with an abstract class. Thank you

Comment: But I shouldn't use the set, because the numberOfLegs doesn't change.

Comment: Yeah, it's up to you, you could make set private so that it could be assigned from within the class only, or better you could use readonly field or property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The NumberOfLegs property setter is not called as you're not changing the value anywhere in your code. The int value is zero by default. You can do one of the following:

1. Define the default value of `numberOfLegs` variable when declaring it:

private int numberOfLegs = 4;

2. Define the `numberOfLegs` value in constructor of Tiger class:

> ```
> public class Tiger : Animal
> {
>   private int numberOfLegs;
>   public Tiger() {
>       numberOfLegs = 4;
>   }
>
>   // ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all wrong...

Don't provide a setter for `numberOfLegs`. Just provide a getter. And then set the number of legs in the constructor, or just set the field directly, like so:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int NumberOfLegs { get; }
}

public class Tiger : Animal
{
    private int numberOfLegs = 4;
    public override int NumberOfLegs
    {
        get
        {
            return numberOfLegs;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason your code wasn't working was because you weren't calling the setter for `Tiger.NumberOfLegs`, but of course if you did so you'd realise how wrong it was:

```
Tiger tiger1 = new Tiger();
tiger1.NumberOfLegs = 100;
int result = tiger1.NumberOfLegs; // Set to 100, but now it's 4! Urk.
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, what is the difference between setting in the constructor and set the field directly?

Comment: @kame The advantage of setting the field directly is that you don't need to set it in the constructors, even if you have several constructors. Other than that, there's no difference for `int` classes. Note also that you could make it a constant rather than a field.